# Spring form select tag doesn't highlight multiple items

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu, spring-form

I've set up a Spring "select" form tag on a jsp page used to input search parameters and display the results. The Spring form select tage allows the user to select more than one item due to the "multiple=true" option. I'm having a problem getting the results display to highlight that multiple items were selected.

It works fine if the user selects a single item, it's highlighted on the re-display of the form (with the entered search parameters still showing in the upper half of the page, and the search results showing in the lower half).

Single item selected:

[image: Single Item Selected]

Single item still shown as selected on response display:

[image: Single item still shown as selected on response display]

However, if multiple items are selected, the multiple selections aren't highlighted at all on the results display:

Multiple Items selected:

[image: Multiple Items selected:]

Multiple items not shown in results display:

[image: Multiple items not shown in results display]

Here's the relevant jsp code:

Action command:

```
<form:form action="/${localePath}/search/ssSearch.do" method="post"  modelAttribute="searchCommand" onsubmit="return trackSearch();">
```

Select code:

```
<tr valign="top"><td>Test Items</td><td>
<form:select path="testItems" multiple="true" size="4">
        <form:option value="">All Items</form:option>
        <form:options items="${testItems}" />
</form:select>
```

Java code:

Here is the  "testItems" code in the SearchCommand object:

```
private String testItems;

    public String getTestItems() {
        return testItems;
    }

    public void setTestItems(String testItems) {
        this.testItems = testItems;
    }
```

Here's the controller request code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*/search/ssSearch.do", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public String searchResults( HttpServletRequest request, 

@ModelAttribute("searchCommand") SearchCommand command,  ModelMap map)
            throws Exception 
    {
        return searchResultsDo(command,  map, request);
    }
```

Here's the code used to populate testItems:

```
    Map<String, String> testItemsMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    testItemsMap.put("item1 name", "item 1 value");
    testItemsMap.put("item2 name", "item 2 value");
    testItemsMap.put("item3 name", "item 3 value");
    testItemsMap.put("item4 name", "item 4 value");
    testItemsMap.put("item5 name", "item 5 value");
    testItemsMap.put("item6 name", "item 6 value");
    testItemsMap.put("item7 name", "item 7 value");
    testItemsMap.put("item8 name", "item 8 value");

    map.addAttribute("testItems", testItemsMap);
```

How can I get multiple selected items to be highlighted on the response page?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to collect a map of selected items in code and then refer to it in the jsp as follows:

```
                <form:select path="testItems2" multiple="true" size="4">
                     <form:option value="">All Items</form:option>              
                      <c:forEach items="${testItems2}" var="testItem2">
                       <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${not empty items2SelectedMap[testItem2.key]}">
                          <form:option value="${testItem2.key}" selected="true">${testItem2.value}</form:option>
                          </c:when>
                          <c:otherwise>
                          <form:option value="${testItem2.key}" >${testItem2.value}</form:option>
                        </c:otherwise>                            
                       </c:choose>
                    </c:forEach>                            
                </form:select>
```

Java code:

```
        Map<String, String> testItemsMap2 = new TreeMap<String, String>();

        List<String> items2SelectedList = null;
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(command.getTestItems2())){
            String[] items2Selected = command.getTestItems2().split(",");
            items2SelectedList = Arrays.asList(items2Selected);
        }


        Map<String, String> items2SelectedMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if (items2SelectedList != null) {
            for (String item2 : items2SelectedList) {
                items2SelectedMap.put(item2, item2);
            }
        }
        map.addAttribute("items2SelectedMap", items2SelectedMap);
```